# CSS Text Overflow

Tags: html, css, text, overflow

I have a series of nested divs in which I am trying to have one piece of text, "TICKET NAME", overflow onto two others.

Here's a picture of the undesired results:

[image]

And here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Game</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<div id="game_head">

    <div id="timer">
    </div>

    <div id="flags">
        <div id="best_of">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="team_1">
        <span class="team_name">Team 1</span>
    </div>

    <div id="ticket">
        <span class="versus">VS</span>
        <span class="ticket_name">TICKET NAME</span>
    </div>

    <div id="team_2">
        <span class="team_name">Team 2</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="game_body">

</div>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
#game_head {
    height: 62px;
    width: 555px;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
#timer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 26%;
    background-color:#111;
    float:left;
}
#flags {
    height: 100%;
    width: 4%;
    background-color:#333;
    float:left;
}
#best_of{
    height:33%;
    background-color:#F00;  
}
#team_1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 31.5%;
    background-color:#999;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    display:table;
}
#team_2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 31.5%;
    background-color:#999;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    display:table;
}
#ticket {
    height: 100%;
    width: 7%;
    background-color:#333;
    float:left;
    overflow:visible;
}
span.ticket_name{
    color:#FFF; 
}
span.team_name{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
span.versus{
    color:#F00;
}
```

How would I go about making the "TICKET NAME" text be centered in the "ticket" div but spill over into the "team_1" and "team_2" divs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well you could make all the divs absolute and then set the z-index of the ticket to greater than the rest and have it wider than them as well